# Asp.net MVC Seed Method Doesn't Run on Publishing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, seed

When i published my project for the first time, seed method run and insert the data to the tables. But when i have changed the seed method with more data, seed method did not work.

And: Shoud i set false "AutomaticMigrationsEnabled" and "AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed" parameters ?

**My Configuration File as Below :**

```
 internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ModulericaV1.Models.ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;

        }

        protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            this.AddUserAndRoles();
        }


        bool AddUserAndRoles()
        {
            bool success = false;

            var idManager = new IdentityManager();
            success = idManager.CreateRole("Admin");
            if (!success == true) return success;

            success = idManager.CreateRole("HR_Admin");
            if (!success == true) return success;

            success = idManager.CreateRole("HR_Visitor");
            if (!success) return success;


            var newUser = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                UserName = "pascal",
                FirstName = "umki",
                LastName = "umkiii",
                Email = "asdfads@asdas.com"
            };

            success = idManager.CreateUser(newUser, "Password1");
            if (!success) return success;

            success = idManager.AddUserToRole(newUser.Id, "Admin");
            if (!success) return success;

            return success;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an AutoMapper you may want to configure it in your Global.asax.cs file.
I just did it by using the following line:

```
var autoMapperConfig = new AutoMapperConfig(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
autoMapperConfig.Execute();
```

and to set the "AutoMapperConfig" you can use the code [here](https://github.com/NikolayIT/BlogSystem/blob/master/Source/BlogSystem.Web/Infrastructure/Mapping/AutoMapperConfig.cs)

Answer (score 0):

Your Migration Configuration should look like this :

```
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }
```

You may also need to save changes at the end.

```
    context.SaveChanges();
```